# Xoom adb drivers

Tags: android

I cannot get Eclipse to see my Xoom. I have usb debugging turned on, and I can see all the xoom files in explorer, but the device fails to show up in Eclipse. Does anyone know what the procedure is to get this working?

Comment: I think he means inside the File Explorer view in Eclipse. The device doesn't have to be mounted to see the the files on it in this window for me.

Comment: have you linked the Xoom settings to your project? If not right click on your project, go to properties-> andriod and link your project.

Comment: I mean I can see the xoom files in Windows explorer. I normally debug in Eclipse with a droid. When I connect my xoom, Eclipse does not see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to go to your Device Manager (Depending on the Windows Version) There should the Xoom appear as an USB Device if there is a red ! or something like this showing a driver is missing you can then right click on it and say install drivers. In the following dialog select find the drivers on the PC and then open the folder on the Xoom containing the windows drivers.

That would be the standard way. I have no Xoom so I can't verify that is working with it.

Comment: OK, thanks, that worked! I had to find the drivers though, which were here, in case anyone else needs them - http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers

Answer (score 11):

I know this is been answered, but I had some trouble myself locating the drivers, so this is for anyone else who may need them:

For [standard user, not development](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/USB_Drivers/)

For [eclipse](http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers/)

Comment: Great tip and link for Eclipse debugging. I installed the "Driver with MotoHelper" from that page which immediately updated my drivers and the device showed up in the Eclipse "Devices" tab. Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome. I really like the StackExchange community. A network of helpful geeks :)

Comment: @kurtzmarc, works for me. Once you're on the page, go under Downloads and select USB drives for devices. http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers

Comment: Sorry - should have said that the first link is no longer a direct link and now redirects to a generic support page. Clicking the "USB drivers for devices" link you suggested takes you to the second link anyway so the first link doesn't really help if all you want are the drivers.

Comment: Yup, seems that the links have changed over time. Feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the Eclipse driver noted by Ayyoudy from [here](http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers), but found that I had to turn USB Debugging off on the XOOM (`Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging`), then install the drivers, unplug the XOOM, reboot, and then turn USB debugging back on and plug it back in after the reboot completed.  (The key is probably to unplug the XOOM when you're modifying the USB Debugging setting.)

Answer (score 1):

The links posted in this question are no longer working!

The current (at time of writing) link is as follows:
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Also please make sure you install with admin rights or as an administrator! I've just spent the last few hours trying to work out why adb wont see my xoom 1, and it was because I wasn't installing as an administrator on windows!

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 7, 64 bit, following worked: Disconnect the device. Install the driver (Motorola Device Manager). After that, connect the device. When connected, enable USB-debugging. The device will be visible in the DDMS.
In my opinion it's important, that the the device is unconnected while installing the MDM.